# Unity : How to test Oculus OVRinput through the editor? Workflow question

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus, oculusgo

Here is my problem,

I'm using unity 2017.4.30 to develop an Oculus Go application. If anyone else has done this before you know that you can get Unity to build an APK and upload to the headset to test your software.

At the moment we are writing code to do with OVR Utilities, specifically OVRInput which basically is to do with the Oculus Go controller interacting with canvas or objects etc.

What I want to be able to do is test code we are writing in the editor and not have to upload the APK each time to test it. It seems some things like OVRCamera rig work in the editor fine but the controllers only show up when you run from the Oculus Go itself.

Any ideas how we could 'simulate' or 'virtualize' OVR controller in the editor so I can just click things with my mouse?

Thanks for reading,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want to write your own controller simulator, I'd suggest using the method oculus quest dev's have been using to quickly debug their game, which involves emulating a rift by using programs like ALVR or VirtualDesktop.

If set up correctly you'll be able to just press the play button in unity and instantly see your game on the oculus go.

Comment: After my research, i  would have to agree this is the way to do it. Doesn't seem like any other alternative

Comment: Yea not until oculus link I suppose. I really hope they allow usb debugging then.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was the Oculus Link. When the Quest was connected to the PC via Link the Quest controllers where emulated inside unity. Problem solved.